# No such file using thunar

Tags: cd-command, thunar, ubuntu-mate

This is really frustrating.

The directory exists.

```
andy@7 /media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin>
```

How do I fix this?

```
cd: /media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin/: No such file or directory
Thunar: Failed to open "/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin/": Error when getting information for file “/media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin”: No such file or directory
```

Comment: well, if both `cd` and `Thunar` agree that it doesn't exist, chances are it doesn't exist. Since you disagree, you must have some strong indication that it does in fact exist. How do you figure?

Comment: @Marcus Müller andy@7 /media/andy/5b4b2ae5-9aaa-4559-9f41-afb313998c75/home/andy/bin>

Comment: is it possible the directory disappeared in the meantime?

Comment: Are you being serious? :-)  @Marcus Müller

Comment: yes, I am serious! /media does sound like an external storage device, and these can be removed, have flimsy connectors, unreliable power etc

Comment: Re-read my edited post. It shows the directory exists. @Marcus Müller

Comment: it shows the directory *existed* (when you changed your shell directory to it) and it shows the directory *no longer exists* (when you tried to open in Thunar/cd to it).

Comment: so the question really is how we can help you solve that issue – the directory isn't there anymore.

Comment: To verify that's the case (might not be completely realiable and depend on the shell and the filesystem): in the shell still within the directory, run `cd .` which should normally be a no-op, but would fail if the directory was deleted. reproducer: `mkdir /tmp/foo; cd /tmp/foo; rmdir /tmp/foo; cd .` => `cd: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory`